# Rails Seed with nested creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I've created a bunch of models for an app I'm working with, and I want to seed them using the seeds.rb file. Problem is, I've nested the creation of one model inside the other (not sure how else to say that), such that when an "Animal" is created, it should automatically create a set of "Packages."

To illustrate, this is in my animal.rb file (details unimportant -- it's just building a set of packages based on the input animal data):

```
after_create :create_packages

  def create_packages
    @cut_list = Cut.where(:animal_type => self.animal_type)
    @cut_list.each do |c|
        Package.create!(:animal_id => self.id, :cut_id => c.id, 
            :original => (self.weight * (c.percent)/100) / c.package_weight, 
            :left => (self.weight * (c.percent)/100) / c.package_weight)
    end
  end
```

In other words, packages, which belong_to animals, are auto-created when an animal is created -- if the animal is created on my app. With the seed, however, just doing this:

```
Animal.create(
        :name => 'Donald Trump',
        :animal_type => "Pig",
        :breed => "Hungarian",
        :weight => 800,
        :farm => "The Piggie Farm",
        :photo => "NA"
    )
```

doesn't build out the associated packages, and since I've built display of packages into my animals show pages, if I reset the db and run an animals/# page, I get an error suggesting that no packages exist for their attributes to be displayed.

Is there any way to get seed data to automatically generate its associated data (that is, to literally call my create method and follow the after_create command), so that I don't have to manufacture seed data for all of the packages that should be auto-generated?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just do this: a = Animal.create(...) a.create_packages?

Comment: Callbacks should occur normally when seeding, are you sure there aren't any validation fails happening? Try using `create!` to see any errors.